# how to create msi installer in VS2010 with custom licence validation

Tags: c#, licensing, license-key, vsinstaller

I have 2 functions:`getLicence()` which returns `licencekey` as string and `validateLicence()` which returns true if validation successful.I have following requirements

- I want to create msi installer in VS 2010 which calls that `getLicence()` and shows the `licencekey`.
- and at the same time it will ask to enter  `licencekey` and call the `validateLicence()`
  if validation successful,it will installed else not installed showing message "Invalid Licence key";

`getLicenceKey()` uses `AesCryptoServiceProvider` to encrypt the machinename and generate the `licencekey` and `validateLicence()` takes the licence key entered by the user and decrypt and validate.

I am using C# (WCF)
I am able to create a MSI installer but I don't know how to call these two functions by the installer (so that user having licencekey can install my application only on one machine).

Comment: please show some source code... what have you tried ? what is not working ?

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you'll want to look into Custom Actions - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9cdb5eda.aspx